# Предотвратить появление двух AlertDialog одновременно

Tags: java, android, mutex, dialog

При запуске приложения происходят 2 проверки: на первый запуск и на авторизацию.
Если запуск приложения происходит впервые, то появляется диалог предупреждающий, что все настройки будут выставлены в default. Если флаг авторизации  = false, то всплывает диалог с выбором способа авторизации. 
При первом запуске приложения т.к. настройки еще не произведены и авторизация не выполнена всплывают оба alerta'а и один перекрывает другой. То есть они вызываются одновременно, а мне необходимо, чтобы они вызывались последовательно. 
Как я пытался решить эту проблему:
В условии появления диалога на авторизацию я добавлял условие, что приложение запускается не впервые, а в случае первого запуска, вызывал AlertDialog авторизации из обработчика нажатия на кнопку первого диалога:

```
.setNeutralButton("Ок", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    //здесь добавлял вызов второго AlertDialog
                    dialogInterface.cancel();                       
                }
            });
```

Но такая реализация мне не очень нравится. Хотя бы потому, что вызов диалога авторизации происходит из двух разных мест.
Хотелось бы получить советы как это можно реализовать по-другому.
Я поставил в метках к вопросу "mutex", по этому посматриваю в эту сторону.
Спасибо за Ваши ответы.

Comment: для одного из диалогов проверять два условия и выводить, например, авторизацию, только если неавторизирован и не первый запуск?

Comment: Это конечно же очевидный способ) Спасибо. Я так пытался, но в итоге хотел бы разобраться с другими возможностями: например приостановить асинхронный поток. Потому что в случае с условиями реализация получается кривая и мне она не нравится.

Comment: тогда в своем вопросе вам нужно изложить подробнее, в чем именно проблема, какие решения не подходят и тд. Никто не в курсе ваших особых условий, искривляющих реализацию, как вы понимаете, а гадать, что именно вам подойдет для ее выпрямления - это не метод решения проблем на данном ресурсе

Comment: @pavlofff, давайте тогда я попытаюсь уточнить по порядку. 
Если отталкиваться от смысла моей задачи, то можно ее реализовать несколько по другому, не вызывая 2 alert'a (просто как-либо обыграть события). Но я хотел бы научиться делать именно так, потому что это может пригодиться в дальнейшем. 
Но моя проблема заключается в том, что при выполнении обоих условий всплывают 2 alert'a одновременно, а мне нужно, чтобы всплывали один за другим. Сперва проверяю приложение на условие первого запуска, и если это так, то выставляю все SharedPreferences "по умолчанию", и вывожу AlertDialog.

Comment: Тем временем, когда AlertDialog уже появился, в коде активити происходит проверка второго условия на авторизацию. Смысл - заставить ждать вторую проверку. По идее, можно её произвести по закрытию первого AlertDialog (задать в обработчике нажатия на кнопку .setNeutralButton()). При этом в onCreate Activity выполнить проверку на 2 условия: первый запуск и необходимость авторизации. Но мне просто кажется это решение неправильным. Все сводится к тому, чтобы просто научиться запускать 2 диалога один за другим по очереди.

Comment: уточнения нужно добавить в вопрос, а не в комментарии к нему. кнопка "править" под вопросом.